How to exit a shell script when a subshell fails and also using read
Following on this post
I have this bash script that I would expect to terminate entirely upon hitting the false and yet, it doesn't. I recognize I am doing things slightly different that the linked post.
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

function thing() {
  false
  echo "thing1|thing2|thing3"
}
IFS='|' read -r one two three <<< "$(thing )"
echo "${one} ${two} ${three}"
echo "done"

Output:
thing1 thing2 thing3
done

Ideally I'd like to do this in zsh but I also get behavior I don't want:

#!/usr/bin/env zsh
set -Eeuo pipefail

function thing() {
  false
  echo "thing1|thing2|thing3"
}
IFS='|' read -r one two three <<< "$(thing )"
echo "${one} ${two} ${three}"
echo "done"


output:
  
done

How to make this work?

You can do
IFS='|' read -r one two three < <(thing)

but checking for an error explicitly as William suggests in his answer is better.

Storing variables and result code:  { read -r line;case $line in RC:*) rc=${line#RC:};; *) IFS='|' read -r one two three <<<"$line";IFS=: read -r _ rc;; esac;}< <(thing;echo RC:$?);declare -p one two three rc

In general, you should never rely on errexit (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).  For this particular case, I don't think you can use the herestring, but you could do something like:
#!/bin/sh

thing() {
        return 1
        echo "thing1|thing2|thing3"
}

text=$(thing) || exit 1
IFS='|' read -r one two three <<< "${text}"
echo "${one} ${two} ${three}"
echo "done"

Explicit is better than implicit, and ... || exit 1 is a beautiful thing to see.

I think this question has already an answer here. Anyway, using herestring could help: { read -r line;case $line in RC:*) rc=${line#RC:};; *) IFS='|' read -r one two three <<<"$line";IFS=: read -r _ rc;; esac;}< <(thing;echo RC:$?);declare -p one two three rc

Looks like it's due to putting everything inline with a herestring. I'll make it explicit
